# Can Clang warn me when I might throw an exception from a `noexcept` destructor?

Tags: c++11, exception, clang, clang++, noexcept

C++11 specifies destructors as `noexcept` by default. Is there a way I can get Clang to report cases where my `noexcept` destructors might throw an exception (and hence call `std::terminate`)?

Comment: Are you asking for a solution for the halting problem? **YES**, unless you want many mis-detections either way. And anyway, the rules are a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes I'm asking for a solution to the halting problem. Surely between Turing and now the problem has been solved and will be detectable in c++11, if not '14? /s

Comment: @Deduplicator What are the complications to the rules? I'm new to this specific issue, but figured e.g., some kind of exception handling framework was put into place for a `noexcept` destructor that might be leveraged to signal a warning to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, C++ does not specify destructors as `noexcept` by default.
It specifies them as `noexcept(all subobjects destructors are noexcept)`.

Next, we can categorize expressions and statements in one category each of:

1. Never returns, may return, always returns.
2. Never throws, may throw, always throws.

In all of them, **only the first case will be marked** as exceptional.

In order to give good results, the compiler must be able to analyze the program behavior sufficiently to determine whether for any possible state, a throwing expression is ever executed.

If you are happy with far too many warnings about impossible scenarios, you can get a result here.
Conversely, if you only want to warn about blatant cases, you might also get some results.

Trouble is, all the interesting cases devolve to solving [the halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).
And no, we are no further along with it.

Comment: clang++ can check both: never returns (`-Wmissing-noreturn`) and may *not* return (`-Wreturn-type`). Additionally, it `-Winvalid-noreturn` checks that there's no `return` in a `[[noreturn]]` function. If the function is marked as `noexcept`, they could check that all code paths are noexcept (warning, off by default). The difference to `return` is that every `return` is an explicit statement in the function itself.

Comment: Which makes the verifying the noreturn part easy (if all is marked, and you assume all non-marked function *will* return), in comparison. The trouble with noexcept is that much more must be analyzed unless you want too many false positives.

Comment: I appreciate the clarifications on the `noexcept` rules, thanks!